# When do you pay a babysitter?

Tags: babysitting

In general, what is the consensus on when to pay a babysitter? Before services? After?

By how long?

With an established babysitter, how might it be affected by your familiarity with them, or your trust in their abilities, punctuality, etc., if at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my experience, it is when you come home, before the sitter leaves. At that moment you know how long they babysat for and how much extra you owe them for being late (I used to charge double after midnight and double if you're late, so possibly 4x for that last hour.) Bring the right amount of cash home with you if you can, or email them the money while you're all still there. Then the sitter can leave or you can take them home.

There's no real reason to pay them in advance - they can't use the money while they're busy watching your kids - but every reason not to make them wait. If you can arrange to go out and get a sitter, you can arrange a way to pay electronically the moment you get home.

Comment: the question was prompted by an incident where someone tried to convince me that paying in advance (approximately two weeks in advance, in this specific case) was customary and I was told I could look this up. I've found 2 anonymous responses (trolls?) that agreed with this position, and hundreds that corroborate my thought...